# Node How to add Array into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

How can i push an array into an exists array?

```
Cases[caseid].items = itemscase;
```

thats what i tried.

I have some "Cases"

```
for(var c in Cases) {
```

for each Case(s) i want to push different new "items" to an exists array.

The array looks like this:

```
'123':
[ { id: 123,
   skus: [Array],
   name: 'xyz',
   img: '/public/images/cases/10018.png'}
```

now i want to push a new array (itemscase) to that like this

```
'123':
[ { id: 123,
   skus: [Array],
   name: 'xyz',
   img: '/public/images/cases/10018.png'
   items: [Array]}
```

The array itemscase is correct and working and looks like that

```
[ { sku: 12345,
name:
 'testname',
price: 15 }]
```

but for some reason the last run will push only to the last "Cases".
So if i have 10 "Cases" only the last gets items all before not.

Here some more Code.

```
for(var c in Cases) {
    var caseid = Cases[c][0].id;
    for(var i in itemsres) {
      var item = itemsres[i];
      itemscase.push({
        sku: item.sku,
        name: item.name
        price: item.suggested_price_floor
      });
    }
    Cases[caseid].items = itemscase;
}
```

itemsres is also fine, creating itemscase works fine and something.

For me looks like something is wrong with the add an array into another array

I think i do something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to test without the full code, but based on your examples, I suggest you to try out this snippet:

```
Object.keys(Cases).forEach(id => {
    Cases[id].forEach(caseItem => {
        caseItem.items = itemsres.map(x => ({
            sku: x.sku,
            name: x.name,
            price: x.suggested_price_floor,
        }));
    });
});
```

Basically, here I'm looping through all cases using `Object.keys()` when object, and `.forEach()` when array. The `Array.map()` function does what your (empty array + loop + push) is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here the maps adds the `items` to each node using a map.

NOTE: You are not filtering on what items to add where, I suspect you want to add items that match the skus?

Let me know and we can make the right changes.

```js
let Cases = [{
    id: 123,
    skus: [1, 2, 3],
    name: 'xyz',
    img: '/public/images/cases/10018.png'
  },
  {
    id: 234,
    skus: [4, 5, 6],
    name: 'abc',
    img: '/public/images/cases/10019.png'
  }
];

let itemres = [{
    sku: 12345,
    name: 'testname',
    price: 15
  },
  {
    sku: 45677,
    name: 'testname',
    suggested_price_floor: 20
  }

];

// add items to cases 
Cases = Cases.map(c => {
  c.items = itemres.map(i => {
    return {
      sku: i.sku,
      name: i.name,
      price: i.suggested_price_floor
    };
    
})
  return c;
});

console.log(Cases);
```